# How can I get the string name of the function so I can call it in the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have this jsp :

```
<div id="searchGrid">
    <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
</div>
<s:hidden id="hdnFonction" value="<s:property value='fonction'/>" />
<h1><s:property value='fonction'/></h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var fn = window[$("#hdnFonction").val()];

        alert($("#hdnFonction").val());

        fn();
    });
</script>
```

so between h1 tags I have the right value (the string name of a function)

but in the alert box I have the struts2 'property' tag like the struts tag is interpreted after the document ready... which would be strange no ?

Comment: When you say "in the alert box I have the struts2 'property' tag" do you mean that the alert displays "<s:property value='fonction'/>"?

Comment: Sounds like a server issue with not replacing that tag. It's not a JavaScript issue.

Comment: whats the purpose of doing this all when you can do simple like `<s:hidden id="hdnFonction" value=%{fonction} />`, any reason to do this

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi : you are absolutly right... I was complicated the thing... thank you... can I validate your comment ?

Comment: @mlwacosmos:comments are not answers all you can upvote comments to show that they actually helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest Struts2 tags inside of one another like that, so the `<s:property>` tag is being parsed as text, rather than as a Struts2 tag.

You'll have to store the value of `<s:property value="fonction"/>` into a scripting variable, and then use that as the value in your `<s:hidden>` tag.

Comment: You are probably right too... I vote for Umesh Awasthi comment which is the right answer